# Custom error message in @Digits annotation

Tags: java, annotations, message, digits

I am attempting to validate a `BigDecimal` field with the help of Hibernate validation API - using `@Digits` annotation

```
@Digits(integer = 12, fraction = 2, 
        message = "numeric value out of bounds (min 0.01, max 999999999999.99)")
private BigDecimal amount = null;
```

When I pass amount value 123.123 the error message I receive is

> 'Classname.amount' numeric value out of bounds (min 0.01, max 999999999999.99)

but the problem is not an invalid range, but the format. We allow only 2 fractional numbers. 
I want to have two message one for invalid range and second is for an invalid fraction.

is it possible to have two different messages?

I tried Interpolation with Message Expressions but it has a bit limited options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@NotNull
@Positive
@Digits(integer = 12, fraction = 2, message = "${validatedValue > 999999999999.99 ? "
            + "'numeric value out of bounds (min 0.01, max 999999999999.99)':"
            + "'value cannot contain more than two fractional digits.'}")
    private BigDecimal amount;
```

I was able to solve the problem using Interpolation with Message Expressions

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
@DecimalMin( value = "0.01", message ="too small")
@DecimalMax( value = "99999999999", message ="too big")
@Digits( integer=12, fraction=2, message = "bad format")
private BigDecimal amount = null;
```